# Module.scss files merging after build and losing order (thus differ specificity on local and on stage)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, sass

I work on project with a self-made UI kit. Both app and UI kit use React TS components and scss modules (app framework is Next.js).
Our team noticed that some styles are applied differently on stage compared to local. They appeared to be overwritten by UI-kit class selectors (locally it worked vice versa as expected). Thus we started use !important flag to overwrite it again but it does create sort of mess in scss files and I've never had a need to do so working with well-known UI libraries (as mui, ant etc.).

Both kit and app import respective style files as `import s from '*.module.scss';`

I've decided to get rid of this behaviour and noticed while building a prod version of app and merging all those hundreds of `.module.scss` in multiple `.css` chunks it merges class selectors from both UI kit and the app in different chunks and those chunks are applied in different order. So UI kit's selectors now appear higher than app ones thus they become more specific.

[image: Order difference on local and build]

Is there a way to sustain order and specificity of class selectors after build withoud adding specificity manually in the app css code?
I'm sure there is, because I've never encountered such an issue while working with popular UI kits but I just don't know how.